# How to debug magento payment gateways

Tags: php, zend-framework, magento, e-commerce

I am just a little curious. What can I do to make my debugging experience with payment gateways a little easier. On check out, it always does the ajax calls. So there is no way I can print_r() or echo to see the progression. Is there a easier way to do it without destroying nothing. Is it possible to disable the ajax calls and make a regular post.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Short answer is: Do this for non-destructive debugging.

```
Mage::log("Logging a message");
```

Long answer follows.

I haven't done a ton of payement gateway debugging, but many of the payment gateways have a "debug" setting in

```
System -> Configuration -> Sales -> Payment Methods
```

Check the authorize.net option group for an example of this.  If you flip this to the "yes" position debug information will start spewing to the log file.  This assumes you've turned logging on in

```
System -> Configuration -> Advanced -> Developer -> Log Settings
```

You may need to create the log files yourself in

```
var/log/system.log
var/log/exception.log
```

Make sure these files are writable by your web server.

You can also log to these files yourself with the static

```
Mage::log("Logging a message");
```

method call.

Finally, if your payment gateway doesn't have a debug setting, you could always fake it.  All Payment Model (are supposed to) inherit from the following class

```
class Mage_Payment_Model_Method_Abstract
app/code/core/Mage/Payment/Model/Method/Abstract.php
```

This class has a method that determines if debugging is on or off

```
/**
 * Define if debugging is enabled
 *
 * @return bool
 */
public function getDebugFlag()
{
    return $this->getConfigData('debug');
}
```

If there's no debug config flag available, you could temporarily change this method to always return true

```
public function getDebugFlag()
{
    return 1;
    //return $this->getConfigData('debug');
}
```

However, I'm not sure how much debugging the base classes do (meaning if there's no debug flag in the config, that may be because there's no debugging going on in the payment gateway model itself). Worth exploring though.

Good luck!

Comment: I've tried it with authorize.net in the past and I only got the XML transaction sent between servers. It wasn't as useful as I had hoped.

Comment: +1 for good info clockwork, but what else would you have liked to see in the logs?

Comment: I wanted to know the URL it was communicating with, and what function was doing it. I appreciate there are other ways of finding those out so it wasn't that bad.

Comment: although all is good with print_r i'd suggested a xdebug session between your site and Ide do you'd get overview of every single method call and parameters

Answer (score 0):

For AJAX you might find [FirePHP for Magento](http://inchoo.net/ecommerce/magento/magento-firephp-extension/) helpful.

For all situations you can use `Mage::log()` as long as you remember to turn it on first in *System > Configuration > Developer*. It works a lot like `print_r` except it outputs to `/var/log/system.log`.

I often `tailf` that file and have code like this in lots of places:

```
Mage::log(__METHOD__); // prints My_Module_Model_Class::method
Mage::log($object->debug()); // $object is any model or block descending from Varien_Object
```

Comment: for ajax you should use fiddler, for internal http requests you should use logging